# Why calculate Mean Squared Error for Regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, sums-of-squares

Once we fit the model to the points why is it necessary to find the mean squared error? What happens if I don't calculate Mean Squared Error?

Comment: Nothing actually happens if you don't, why would anything happen?

Comment: @Firebug, sometimes bad things can happen, such as partial grade on assignment for incomplete solution

Comment: @Aksakal one never knows the implications and downsides of statistics right :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: to know how close you got to the perfect fit. The model is often fitted by minimizing MSE, so you'd like to know how close you got to ZERO in the end. You can use this metric later to compare models, those with smaller MSE fit better to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would happen if you do not do that. However MSE is one way to measure the effectiveness of your model. You can do MAPE, MAE or SMAPE.
This is the same as classification accuracy otherwise how would you know your model is good?